# ffmpeg problem in ubuntu (libavcodec.so)

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I run Ubuntu and try to use the ffmpeg wrapper in Java from here:
http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

It seems to work fine on other systems, but in Ubuntu the project crashes
with the following mistake:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up
function 'avcodec_decode_video2': /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libavcodec.so:
undefined symbol: avcodec_decode_video2

ffmpeg is working great from the command line, though.

JavaCV author recommended me to check this link:
http://linux-tipps.blogspot.com/2009/05/pretending-package-is-installed-by.html

Probably I'm doing something wrong, but it cannot reinstall libavcodec51
like this.

So the questions are:
1. Is those solution above a good one so I should bring it to success
somehow?
2. What are the other ways to solve the problem?

Thank you for your suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 0):

libavcodec is built with C linkage, but the header does not place the declarations around an `extern "C"` wrapper when built with C++. If the Java Native Interface wrapper to libavcodec is built with a C++ compiler, it will define the functions using C++ linkage. In this case it needs something like:

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec.h>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1
1.First update your Flash player if its asking you to update.
   Download and extract Flash tar.gz.open that folder as root.Now enter following command:

TGS install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64 # cp -v libflashplayer.so /var/lib/mozilla/plugins/
‘libflashplayer.so’ -> ‘/var/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so’

TGS install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64 # cp -v libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/
‘libflashplayer.so’ -> ‘/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so’

TGS install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64 #

2. Update libavcodec

milan@TGS ~ $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next

milan@TGS ~ $ sudo apt-get update

milan@TGS ~ $ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

Method 2

just enable libavcodec in firefox:
type about:config in the address bar, enter
click "I accept the risk" search libavcodec
change media.libavcodec.allow-obsolete;false to true

http://www.techyo.ga/2016/12/solved-libavcodev-may-be-vulnerable-or.html